# Xcode Custom Template

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am working on custom Xcode templates design.  I am able to do simple custom templates with minimum options. I trying find solution on following, that I am not able to do with the existing templates.

1)  I want to have multiple screens in the template wizard, Like Device type a popup option with iPhone, iPad and Universal. Then taping on next another screen with another screen with Language selection popup and core data selection on taping on next again another screen with checkbox selecting some of the third party libs etc. For now I can add only one screen and next it will ask for Project save location.

Is it possible to do something like this?

2)  I want to place a scroll bar in the Project template wizard screen, Like I Have multiple options in the screen but by default the scrolls are not available and all the items are not visible in the wizard window

Thanks